# How to replace Gazebo physics with Mujoco

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ros application that uses ros_control and controller_manager while being simulated in Gazebo in an additional pacakge.

I am interested to use the controllers inside this application with Mujoco instead of Gazebo for which I am writing a new package.

If I have understood correctly one typically writes a new script first using hardware_interface::RobotHW class. Is there a way to avoid this? For example if I can still use most of the current implementations within Gazebo to do this.

In the end also I am hoping in general to have the python api of Mujoco also instead of its C++.

Are there also implementation examples other than gazebo that I can look at?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349059/how-to-replace-gazebo-physics-with-mujoco/) by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/shadow-robot/mujoco_ros_pkgs looks helpful for some amount of ros integration but it doesn't look to help much with gazebo controller plugins.

Try https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers for non-gazebo usage of the gazebo control plugins you are using, you should be able to start up standalone nodes that publish out the results of their control computations on topics, then you could have a python node subscribe to those and talk to mujoco.

http://wiki.ros.org/pid is useful if you want a quick and simple topics-in-topics-out pid controller that doesn't use ros_control, or spend a little more time finding and integrating some non-ros python libraries that do pid or more advanced control.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2022-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0